# "In java variables are initialized before any method is called, even the constructor.". – can anyone provide an example?

Tags: java

"In java variables are initialized before any method is called, even the constructor.". That is, the class's constructor body runs after variable initialization. – can anyone provide an example with detailed explanation??

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think that's true (unless I'm misunderstanding). Where did you read that?

Comment: Instance members are initialized before the constructor is called.

Comment: This question does not comply with StackOverflow rules. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. Maybe you heard that in the context of `static` variables, because:

- It is a variable which belongs to the class and not to object(instance)
- Static variables are initialized only once , at the start of the execution .
- These variables will be initialized first, before the initialization of any instance   variables
- A single copy to be shared by all instances of the class
- A static variable can be accessed directly by the class name and doesn’t need any object.

Comment: How is it not true? [Adarsh's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20429247/833844) makes it seem to be true indeed.

Comment: @EmilLundberg Take a closer look at his examples. In example one it is not `static`, thats why the constructor of the class has to be called in the first place to access the `String s`. In example 2, the `String s` is declared as `static` and can be accessed before the constructor of `Test` is called.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand the misunderstanding. Your point is that the constructor must be called before the member is initialized. My point is that the member has been initialized before execution of the constructor body begins. Both are true.

Comment: Ah, now I get your point. Yes thats true, indeed. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Example 1:**

```
public class Test {
    private final String s = "123";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Test t = new Test();     
    }

    Test() {
       System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Here s is a class variable and can only be accessed by an instance(object) of the class. If you try printing its value in the main method, you won't be able to access the variable as it belongs to the class objects and objects only.

**Example 2:**

```
public class Test {
    private static final String s = "123";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("In main:" + s);
       Test t = new Test();     
    }

    Test() {
       System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

In this case, the class variable is static which means that it can be accessed directly without creating any instance of the class; meaning, the variable does not belong to the objects.

This is precisely why the main method is static, as it needs to be called before any class objects have been created.